# Scala: Pattern matching in tuples

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, tuples

I know the fact that tuples are immutable in Scala. Hence, I am using pattern matching to change my tuples. I have a 2-tuple having two 3-tuple elements, each element being a sequence.  My problem is: 'If the first element of the first tuple is an empty sequence, send some default value.' 
My code looks something like this:

```
val (fooTuple, barTuple) = 
{
// function that returns a 2-tuple with elements that are 3-tuples
((a, b, c), (d, e, f)) //Each of these is a sequence
} match {
case ((Seq(), x, y), z) => ((Seq("default"), x, y), z)
}
```

It throws a `MatchError` printing the value of `((a, b, c), (d, e, f))`
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It failed for cases when your first elements is not empty, you can fix this by handling other cases:

```
val (fooTuple, barTuple) = 
{
// function that returns a 2-tuple with elements that are 3-tuples
((a, b, c), (d, e, f)) //Each of these is a sequence
} match {
  case ((Seq(), x, y), z) => ((Seq("default"), x, y), z)
  case other => other
}
```

Where all other cases would be handled by `case other => other`